# Internet Explorer 11 not sending *non-secure* cookie (set over HTTPS) over HTTP

Tags: internet-explorer, cookies, internet-explorer-11

I've a problem with using IE11 to debug a web app. Using Fiddler, I've established a behavioural difference between IE and Chrome when following the same route to the app

The procedure I follow is:

- navigate to https://auth.myco.com
- log in with good username and password
- the response contains a set-cookie instruction for the .myco.com domain
- navigate to http://local.myco.com:12345 (a debug version of the app running in visual studio's webserver)

Here's where the behavioural difference comes - Chrome WILL set the Cookie: header in the request and send the cookie that was set. IE won't set the Cookie header at all, and the app refuses to serve pages

The auth site is consistent in its behaviour, the headers look like:

```
HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Cache-Control: private
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Location: /loggedin/
Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.5
Set-Cookie: .ASPXFORMSAUTH=; domain=.myco.com; expires=Wed, 17-Aug-2016 08:43:54 GMT; path=/; secure; HttpOnly
Set-Cookie: .ASPXFORMSAUTH=BLAHBLAHBLAH; domain=.myco.com; path=/; HttpOnly
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
Date: Thu, 18 Aug 2016 08:43:54 GMT
Content-Length: 128
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
```

Here's IE making a request to the "you're logged in" page the authsite redirects to after successful login (cookie present):

```
GET https://auth.myco.com/loggedin/ HTTP/1.1
Accept: text/html, application/xhtml+xml, image/jxr, */*
Referer: https://auth.myco.com/
Accept-Language: en-GB,en;q=0.7,ja;q=0.3
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Host: auth.myco.com
Connection: Keep-Alive
Cache-Control: no-cache
DNT: 1
Cookie: ASP.NET_SessionId=sao3x3skzhcgquylfcaokvt0; .ASPXFORMSAUTH=BLAHBLAHBLAH
```

Then we change the address bar to http://local.myco.com:54321 (resolves to 127.0.0.1) and bam! the cookie is gone.. but it wasn't set with the "secure" flag!

```
GET http://local.myco.com:12345/ HTTP/1.1
Accept: */*
Accept-Language: en-GB,en;q=0.7,ja;q=0.3
User-Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 10.0; WOW64; Trident/7.0; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; .NET CLR 3.5.30729)
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Host: local.myco.com:12345
Connection: Keep-Alive
```

As noted, all the other browsers on my system play fine with this; it's just IE that bins the auth cookie..

Any clues on where to go next